# How to unit test a multi module angular product

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-mock

I've got an angular project which contains multiple modules which are used to separate the logic of the project. Obviously plenty of these modules have dependencies on other modules defined within the project.

As an example I have a module called 'myapp.shared.mixpanel' which contains a service called mixpanelService for sending tracking events. There is another module called 'myapp.feature' which has a dependency on 'myapp.shared.mixpanel' so that it can access the mixpanelService.

```
angular.module('myapp.feature', ['myapp.shared.mixpanel']);
```

When I test a controller inside the 'myapp.feature' module I load the module:

```
angular.mock.module('myapp.feature');
```

but this has a dependency on 'myapp.shared.mixpanel'.

Is there a way to prevent the "real" version of this module from being loaded as a dependency and instead load an "empty" version of the dependent modules which I can add mock services/controllers/etc to later?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$provide` override method.

> As an example I have a module called **'myapp.shared.mixpanel'** which contains a service called **mixpanelService** for sending tracking events. There is another module called **'myapp.feature'** which has a dependency on **'myapp.shared.mixpanel'** so that it can access the **mixpanelService**.

In your controller test (the controller in `myapp.feature`) you would do the following:

```
var $scope, mixPanelService;

beforeEach(function () {
  mixPanelService = {};

  module('myapp.feature', function ($provide) {
    // Here we are $providing a value of the same name to our current module. This is equivalent to the module.config method.
    $provide.value('mixPanelService', mixPanelService);
  });

  inject(function ($controller, $injector) {
    $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
    mixPanelService = $injector.get('mixPanelService');       

    $controller('yourController', {
      $scope: $scope
      mixPanelService: mixPanelService
    });
  });

  // Add the required methods to mixPanelService (here I'm using sinon.stub())

  mixPanelService.someMethodMyControllerIsUsing = sinon.stub();
});
```

Now you don't have to worry about broken dependencies, nor do you have to worry about implementation details that should be tested in another isolated unit test.

`mixPanelService` is stubbed out and available in your module, and you didn't have to instantiate the `.shared.mixpanel` in a spec suite that has *nothing* to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can override a previously registered module with the same name (see [Creation versus Retrieval](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval)). So basically you can override your dependency-module with empty one in your test:

```
angular.module('myapp.shared.mixpanel', []);
angular.mock.module('myapp.feature');
```

Comment: I tried this. But the problem with that approach is when, in another test spec, I try to load the mixpanel module for testing (angular.mock.module('myapp.shared.mixpanel')). This doesn't work because the previous test has wiped the content the module, so I can't test it.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. I do not get the point of mocking a module though, because it is like a container for controllers/services/etc, you use them but not the module itself. If you get to mocking an entire module, all it's original controllers/services/etc will be gone, but all dependent modules still want these services and they still call their methods, you'll eventually end up mocking services to satisfy dependencies, but not the module.

Comment: Module allows to register controllers/services/etc, but it does not execute them, they are instantiated only when injected or explicitly called. The only side effect I am aware of a module could bring is that it calls it's `.config()` and `.run()` blocks, otherwise it should not influence dependent modules by itself. All the influence and dependency chains come from it's  services, which you use in dependent modules.

Comment: The problem with using the real modules instead of mock module is that real modules will have their own dependencies which can cause a dependency cascade in the tests. i.e. Module Under Test -dependson-> module 1 -dependson-> module 2 -dependson-> module 3 ... etc etc. It would be easier just to load a mock version of module 1 which has NO dependencies.

Comment: I've tried to do this in some hacky ways, like backing up module dependencies and services registered on it, overriding the module before test and then trying to re-init it when the test has finished, but failed. I personally do not see any approach to mock the entire module yet, but I think I'll keep that answer + comments, maybe it could help somebody to give you a complete answer.